# Understanding the proof of product of completely regular space is completely regular under product topology

Tags: general-topology

Below is the proof:

> **Proof.** Let $a=\prod_{i\in I}a_i\in\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and $U$ be any open set containing $a$. Then there exists a finite subset $J$ of $I$ and sets $U_i\in\tau_i$ such that
> $$a\in\prod_{i\in I}U_i\subseteq U$$
> where $U_i=X_i$ for all $i\in I\setminus J$. As $(X_j,\tau_j)$ is completely regular for each $j\in J$, there exists a continuous mapping $f_j:(X_j,\tau_j)\longrightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f_j(a_j)=0$ and $f_j(y)=1$, for all $y\in X_j\setminus U_j$. Then $f_j\circ p_j:\prod_{i\in I}(X_i,\tau_i)\longrightarrow[0,1]$, where $p_j$ denotes the projection of $\prod_{i\in I}(X_i,\tau_i)$ onto $(X_j,\tau_j)$.
>
> If we put $f(x)=\max\{f_j\circ p_j(x):\ j\in J\}$, for all $x\in\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ then $f:\prod_{i\in I}(X_i,\tau_i)\longrightarrow[0,1]$ is continuous (as $J$ is finite). Further, $f(a)=0$ while $f(y)=1$ for all $y\in X\setminus U$. So $\prod_{i\in I}(X_i,\tau_i)$ is completely regular. $\qquad\square$

I am trying to understand the line $f(x)=\max\{f_j(p_j(x)):\ j\in J\}$. What does this function mean and what is the point of it? What exactly are we taking the max of? We have not assumed that any of the $X_i$ are ordered or are sets that even contains a max.

Answer (score 3):

For each $j\in J$ you have a continuous function $f_j:X_j\to[0,1]$ such that $f_j(a_j)=0$, and $f_j(y)=1$ for each $y\in X_j\setminus U_j$. Now let $x\in X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$. For each $i\in I$ we have the projection map $p_i:X\to X_i$. In particular, $p_j(x)$ is a point in $X_j$ for each $j\in J$, so we can apply $f_j$ to it to get

$$(f_j\circ p_j)(x)=f_j\big(p_j(x)\big)\in[0,1]\,.$$

That is, for each $j\in J$ we have a number $(f_j\circ p_j)(x)$ in $[0,1]$, and

$$\{(f_j\circ p_j)(x):j\in J\}$$

is therefore a finite subset of $[0,1]$. Since this is a finite set of real numbers it has a maximum element;

$$\max\{(f_j\circ p_j)(x):j\in J\}$$

is that maximum element. We now define a function $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ by setting $f(x)$ equal to this maximum element:

$$f:X\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\max\{(f_j\circ p_j)(x):j\in J\}\,.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
f(a)&=\max\{(f_j\circ p_j)(a):j\in J\}\\
&=\max\left\{f_j\big(p_j(a)\big):j\in J\right\}\\
&=\max\{f_j(a_i):j\in J\}\\
&=0\,,
\end{align*}$$

since $f_j(a_j)=0$ for every $j\in J$. And if $x\in X\setminus U$, there must be a $j\in J$ such that $x_j\in X_j\setminus U_j$. so $(f_j\circ p_j)(x)=f_j(x_j)=1$, and therefore $f(x)=1$. Thus, $f$ will be the desired function **if** it is continuous, and continuity follows (with a little work) from the fact that $J$ is finite. (If you have trouble proving this, try it first on the assumption that $|J|=2$.)

Comment: It is definitely a strange function. Now to show that is is continuous we take any open set of [0,1] and show the preimage is open. So let's take [0,1/2). An element belong to the preimage  its its image is in [0,1/2) so that means the max of one of its factor under the mapping $(f_j(p_j)$ is in [0,1/2). What would the preimage of this even look like?

Comment: @willyx888: For each $j\in J$ let $$V_j=f_j^{-1}\left[f_j^{-1}\left[0,\frac12\right)\right]\,,$$ and for each $i\in I\setminus J$ let $V_i=X_i$. Then $$f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac12\right)\right]=\prod_{i\in I}V_i\,.$$

Comment: @willyx888: The intuitive idea is that the function $f_j$ is a bit like a distance function, telling you (roughly speaking) how far from $a_j$ any point of $X_j$ is. For each $x\in X$ we look at the coordinates $x_j$ of $x$ for the finitely many $j\in J$, see how ‘far’ each is from the corresponding $a_j$, and use that ‘distance’ to say how ‘far’ $x$ is from $a$. Of course these aren’t real distances, since we’re not dealing with metrics, but the idea is similar.